# How send GPS location from android to asp?

Tags: android, asp.net, gps

I have a graduate project.. and i should send the GPS location from android device using GPRS to asp.net website.so what method i should use? HTTP request or other web service. And what is the code i should use in android device and in asp page?!
Thanks in advance..

Comment: So, basically you want someone to do the project for you?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

What you're asking is a very elementary question, yet you describe it as a graduate project task. I genuinely fear for the next generation of software developers...

Anyway, here's the list of problems with your post:

- GPRS (General Packet Radio Service) is a packet-based telecoms system for mobile radio (a predecessor to 3G in our phones). You're thinking of GPS (Global Positioning System). Besides the fact both are available in most smartphone handsets, they are completely different concepts.
- "ASP" is ambiguous and can refer to the Active Scripting/COM-based "Active Server Pages" (often refered to as Classic ASP, as development ended in 1999 with the release of Windows 2000), or it can refer to the newer ASP.NET. You should clarify that.
- "HTTP request or other web service" betrays your lack of understanding of HTTP, because every web service call is implemented using a HTTP request.
- Asking "What is code should I use" is tantamount to telling us to solve your question for you, without you applying any original investigation or research on your part. You also haven't explained what you're doing or why you're doing it, which can lead to the "XY Problem" occurring.

I will point you in the right direction, but I won't give you the answer (i.e. I'll give you just enough rope to hang yourself with):

1. Use Android's geolocation APIs in an Android application to retrieve the device's coordinates, presumably in NMEA format, or as a single Latitude/Longitude coordinate string representation.
2. Create a simple IHttpHandler (there is no need to use WebForms (a "page") or MVC for this, as this is a data service, there is on human-facing HTML being returned). This IHttpHandler would accept data in a POST request's body (as this seems more semantically correct than using the GET verb and querystring parameters).
3. In Android, create an outgoing HTTP POST request and serialise the data you retrieved in step 1 to the POST request body, then submit it.

Comment: +1, I'm hoping we're misunderstanding the use of "graduate" in this case...

Comment: "*I genuinely fear for the next generation of software developers...*" Amen... amen.

Comment: I have already done every thing in the project..now i'm using http request to send the data but i'm searching for a better way than http request because it is unsecured...